# Underscore js times series

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using UnderscoreJs with nodejs and have a need for the [`_.times()`](http://underscorejs.org/#times) method.  times() will invoke a function X number of times

This works as expected, however I need to iterate in a series, instead of in parallel which this appears to be doing.

Any idea if there's a way to use this in series w/ callback methods?

Comment: [`_.times`](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L891) is just a `for` loop so it does execute in series. Do you have your terminology backwards?

Comment: It doesn't wait for the previous for loop to finish executing, so without a callback to invoke the next, processes that take some time wont always be complete before the next iteration.

Comment: You're using an asynchronous callback then. Look at [the source](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L891) if you don't believe me, `_.times` is just `for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) iterator.call(context, i);`. You must be leaving something important out of your question, something like what your callback is doing.

Comment: Right, but node.js is asynchronous so even if I have a for loop, the code inside the for loop, won't "wait" until the previous iteration is complete.

Comment: Um no, I think you're confused. The function that you're handing to `_.times` is calling async functions, node isn't automatically spawning a separate thread for each iteration of a `for` loop. So, what is your callback function doing that is asynchronous and what sorts of callbacks does that support?

Comment: Ok, so the function that's being called selects a document and inserts a document into MongoDB.  It can support callbacks, but none are being used, not sure how would you use a callback from another function, in conjunction with times.  Maybe 250R's response below is the answer? I'll have to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given something like this:

```
function f() {
    some_async_call({ callback: function(err, results) {...})
}
_(3).times(f);
```

Then the three `f` calls will happen in series but the `some_async_call` calls won't necessarily happen in series because they're asynchronous.

If you want to force your calls to run in series then you need to use the callback on the async call to launch the next one in the series:

```
function f(times, step) {
    step = step || 0;
    some_async_call({
        callback: function(err, results) {
            // Do something with `err` and `results`...
            if(step < times)
                f(times, step + 1);
        }
    });
}
f(3);
```

That approach will execute the three `some_async_calls` in series but, alas, the initial `f(3)` will return immediately. One solution to that problem is, of course, another callback:

```
function f(from_n, upto, and_finally) {
    some_async_call({
        callback: function(err, results) {
            // Do something with `err` and `results`...
            if(from_n < upto)
                f(from_n + 1, upto, and_finally);
            else
                and_finally();
        }
    });
}
f(0, 3, function() { console.log('all done') });
```

Where does `_.times` in with all this? No where really. [`_.times` is just a `for` loop](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L891):

```
_.times = function(n, iterator, context) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) iterator.call(context, i);
};
```

`_.times` exists for completeness and to allow you to add `for` loop when using [`_.chain`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#chain). You could probably shoe-horn it in if you really wanted to but you would be making a big ugly mess instead of simplifying your code.

You could use 250R's async idea but you'd have to build an array of three functions but [`_.range`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#range) and [`_.map`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#map) would be more appropriate for that than `_.times`:

```
// Untested off the top of my head code...

function f(callback) {
    some_async_call({
        callback: function(err, results) {
            // Deal with `err` and `results`...
            callback();
        }
    });
}

var three_fs = _(3).range().map(function() { return f });
async.series(three_fs);
```

But you still have to modify `f` to have a callback function and if you're always calling `f` three times then:

```
async.series([f, f, f]);
```

might be better than dynamically building the array with `_.range` and `_.map`.

The real lesson here is that once you get into asynchronous function calls, you end up implementing all your logic as callbacks calling callbacks calling callbacks, callbacks all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

This **async** library might get you started
https://github.com/caolan/async#series

Or if you want to do it yourself, the idea is to do recursive calls after each function callback is called, here's the source code https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L101

Comment: I use async, but how would I define it to execute x number of times?

Comment: You could do something like _.times(3, function(){functionArray.push(theFunction);}) to get theFunction() into the array and then async.series(functionArray)